# HasFile is not a member of System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, file-upload

Hi i'm currently creating a program which uploads and view a file using vb.net.
As of now i am having error saying HasFile is not a member of System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button as well as the "FileName" and "SaveAs" ..

This is my Code :

```
 Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FileUpload1.Click

    cmd.CommandText = "select max(fid) from Filedb"
    cmd.Connection = con

    Dim chk As Object = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
    If IsDBNull(chk) Then
        f_id = 1
    Else
        cmd.CommandText = "select max(fid) from Filedb"
        cmd.Connection = con
        f_id = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
        f_id += 1
    End If
    If FileUpload1.HasFile Then
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into Filedb(fid,Name) values(" & f_id & ",'" & FileUpload1.FileName & "')"
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close()
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(FileUpload1.FileName))
    End If
    Response.Redirect("../Default.aspx")
End Sub
```

[image]

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It looks like you have just added a `Button` control and changed it's name to `FileUpload1` rather than actually adding a `FileUpload` control.

Comment: Actually i already had that FileUpload1 Control .. i jst ddnt realize instead of renaming FileUpload i renamed Button.. Thanks dude.